# Java collector to Optional<T>

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors

Using Java streams and generics I'm trying to create a `Collector`, that would return me `Optional.empty`, if stream is empty, `Optional<T>` if stream has one item and throw exception if stream has more than one item.

```
public static <T, R extends Optional<T>> Collector<T, ?, R> toOptional() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            list -> {
                if (list.size() > 1) {
                    throw new CollectingException("More than one item found in: " + list);
                }
                if (list.size() == 1) {
                    return Optional.of(list.get(0));
                }
                return Optional.empty();
            }
    );
}
```

However I'm getting an error I don't understand.

```
Required type:
Collector<T,?,R>
Provided:
Collector<Object,Object,Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Optional<T> conforms to R inference variable RR has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: R lower bounds: Optional<T1868063>
```

The desired usage would be

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
Optional<Person> john = people.stream().filter(person->"John".equals(person.getName())).collect(toOptional());
```

Could anyone please explain me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of your method is not correct, instead of:

```
public static <T, R extends Optional<T>> Collector<T, ?, R> toOptional() {
```

You can just use:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> toOptional() {
```

In other words, the method need to return an `Optional` object of type `T` directly, instead of using a separate type parameter `R` that extends `Optional<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76720930/2711488) does already tell you how to declare the method correctly.

However, note that you don’t need this special collector. You can simply use

```java
Collectors.reducing((first, second) -> {
    throw new CollectingException("More than one item found, "
        + "first: " + first + ", second: " + second);
})
```

which does already your intended job. (see [`Collectors.reducing(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)))

- If the stream is empty, an empty `Optional` is returned
- If the stream contains a single element, an `Optional` containing the element is returned
  Note that this approach doesn’t construct a `List` first but directly produces the `Optional`.
- If there are more than one element, the reduction function will be evaluated, to reduce them to a single result, which will throw the intended exception here.
  Note that this approach doesn’t waste resources to collect all unintended elements into a `List` but stops when encountering the second element.

---

When you don’t want to combine this logic with other collectors, you don’t need a collector at all but can use [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) on the Stream directly:

```java
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
Optional<Person> john = people.stream()
    .filter(person -> "John".equals(person.getName()))
    .reduce((first, second) -> {
        throw new CollectingException("More than one item found, "
            + "first: " + first + ", second: " + second);
    });
```

does the same as

```java
Optional<Person> john = people.stream()
    .filter(person -> "John".equals(person.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.reducing((first, second) -> {
        throw new CollectingException("More than one item found, "
            + "first: " + first + ", second: " + second);
    }));
```